# url rewrite rule without www prepend

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have several of these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.es$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://www.domain.it/$1/?lang=es [L,R=301,QSA]
```

to redirect regional users to specific languages. Each rule works as expected but only if the users types www.domain.es. It doesn't if he types domain.es

Is it possible to modify the rule to implement url redirect also from domain.es to www.domain.ti/?lang=es ?

Thanks for your help. I am newbie on url rewriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTTP_HOST regex:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://www.domain.it/$1/?lang=es [L,R=301,QSA]
```

or make the entire subdomain part optional: `^([^.]+\.)?domain\.es$`